# Trying to use code to insert a row into the database and then also display that row after a button is clicked (using CommandText)

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm trying to use code to insert a row into the database and then immediately display that code after after a button is clicked. I'm using C#.

```
comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Store (FirstName, LastName) Values ('" + txtFirstName.Text + "', '" + txtLastName.Text + "')";
```

The above code works . But it won't work if I add the following code (which will work instead):

```
comm.CommandText = "Select FirstName, LastName from Store";
```

When the button is clicked, I want to insert the row (containing information that was just entered from the textbox) into the table and also display that new row  into a form (set up to view the table). I'm trying to get both of the commands to work at the same time, but only the second "Command" works.

Here is what the surrounding code looks like:

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String testVar = txtFirstName.Text;

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(); //where to find db
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["storeConnString"].ConnectionString; //long connection screen.
        conn.Open();

        OleDbCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
        comm.Connection = conn;

        comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Store (FirstName, LastName) Values ('" + txtFirstName.Text + "', '" + txtLastName.Text + "')";
        comm.CommandText = "Select FirstName, LastName from Store";

        OleDbDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
```

(I know I need to use parameters, but I'm going to do that after I figure this out.)

Thanks, Brad

Answer (score 2):

Because after this two lines, your `INSERT` command will not assigned to your `comm` anymore.

```
comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Store (FirstName, LastName) Values ('" + txtFirstName.Text + "', '" + txtLastName.Text + "')";
comm.CommandText = "Select FirstName, LastName from Store";
```

`CommandText` property only have now your `SELECT` stament. Just execute your `INSERT` query with [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) and after use `ExecuteReader` to get your `SELECT` statement result.

```
comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Store (FirstName, LastName) Values ('" + txtFirstName.Text + "', '" + txtLastName.Text + "')";
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
comm.CommandText = "Select FirstName, LastName from Store";
OleDbDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
```

As you said, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for SQL Injection attacks.

And use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection`, `OleDbCommand` and `OleDbDataReader` like;

```
using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(OleDbCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    // Execute your INSERT query here.
    // Also check your INSERT is successfull or not.
    // Assing your SELECT statement to your CommandText property
    using(OleDbDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
    {  
       //
    }
}
```

Comment: If would be interesting to know what kind of database is the one behind the connectionstring. Perhaps it supports also a batch command with two texts separated by semicolon

Comment: @Steve Yeah, it would be nice such a feature but here he assign his SELECT statement to `CommandText` property, not concatenating it with a secmicolon.